# is there an open source template library for matrix computation in C or C++?

Tags: c++, math, open-source, matrix

I am looking for a library with all the functionality that is standard for linear algebra. Such as determinants, matrix inverse, multiplication... but generic.

Octave has the perfect library for double and complex arithmetic, but I need to be able to change the implementation of arithmetic.

Comment: Here's one place to look: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/351/recommendations-for-a-usable-fast-c-matrix-library

Comment: Thanks David! There sure is a lot of stuff to choose from!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eigen is definitely the best matrix library in C++ at the moment.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

I warmly suggest you.

For example this code creates a random 10x10 matrix and compute its inverse:

```
MatrixXd A(10,10);
A.setRandom(10,10);
MatrixXd B = A.inverse();
```

you can have access to all numerical matrix algebra things, such as decompositions, linear system solving and other geometry algorithms.

It's only headers, no external dependency, no installation.
It works for a large range of compilers and is very well mantained and documented.

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea the boost::uBLAS could help you. You could check their docs here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm, this is a basic linear algebra library.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend **[Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)**: it works quickly both on small, fixed-sized matrices and large, dynamically allocated matrices.  However, you may also want to look at [**Armadillo**](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), which has a slightly different set of features; in particular supporting arrays with 3 rather than just 2 indexes (dimensions).

Comment: From personal experience, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) is pretty good at providing functions / APIs that resemble Matlab. This is an important factor to take into account when moving between Matlab and C++ (eg. converting code for production purposes).

Comment: I've never found this to be problematic with Eigen.  It's also to be faster in general (sometimes by a large margin).  So by default I tend to use eigen unless there's some specific reason not to.

Comment: To be honest though; it's mostly laziness: it's so easy to use a header-only library, and since I cross-compile stuff for gcc/msc, I really don't like taking any binary dependencies.  A possible downside for eigen is that it assumes a fair amount of knowledge of implementation details: you can lose quite a bit of performance if you use dynamically allocated matrices where fixed-size is better, or by failing to take into account temporaries and aliasing.  So it's key advantage is a bit fragile.

Comment: I had a thorough look through [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net)'s source code: the developers took pains to make the library alias safe by default (ie. the user doesn't have to worry about effects of aliasing).

The library also automatically handles small matrices and vectors in a different manner, making the speed of small dynamic-sized matrices comparable to fixed-size matrices, without the user needing to explicitly declare fixed-size matrices. 

This is not to say that Eigen is bad, just that I've found Armadillo easier to use.

Comment: @mtall: that's a good start, but that comes at a significant performance cost.  Eigen is also alias-safe by default, but by marking some variables as noalias, you can avoid temporaries which makes a huge difference for small-to-medium sized matrices where a single malloc call can dominate the runtime.  Similarly, just using a separate code flow for small matrices isn't enough - just the runtime branching is a noticable cost for e.g. 8d vectors (not to mention 2d or 3d), and the real problem here again is the dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: BTW, Armadillo also supports fixed-size matrices via `mat::fixed` so perhaps the distinction isn't relevant (anymore?).  You'd need good benchmarks to tell...

Comment: By different handling I meant that Armadillo actually avoids dynamic memory allocation for small matrices and vectors, even if they were originally declared by the user as dynamically sized. This is distinct from explicitly declaring fixed-size matrices.  In the latter case the compiler has extra information to do more thorough optimisation.

Comment: It uses stack allocation?

Comment: Oh I see, it uses an inline 16-element fixed buffer.  That's certainly *much* better than nothing, but it's also going to be much slower than a real fixed-size matrix due to the suboptimal memory density and in particular all those guards coupled with the fact that they likely prohibit useful inlining and subsequent optimizations.  Still, I'd use `mat::fixed` if you can - it's a much more robust solution, performance wise.

Comment: So, reviewing all that I think my conclusion above is still right - Armadillo is a solid option, but unless there's some particular armadillo feature you need, Eigen has a few practical advantages in that it's header only, and has no boost and BLAS dependencies: that makes it easy to port code depending on it to various platforms and without worrying about stuff like 32 vs. 64 bit or OS.  It can also be faster when you want it to be.  Honestly though, the difference isn't very significant.  Other choices: `blaze`, and for big matrices you probably want GPU help anyhow....